# How to remove last comma from each array in foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, html-lists, delimiter

I have a multidimensional array and I am trying to put comma delimiter and remove the last comma from each array so far I try this.

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Honda","Mercedes");
$chunks =(array_chunk($cars,2));
foreach ($chunks as $key) {
    echo "<ul>";
    $data = array();
    foreach ($key as $value) {
        $data[] ="<li>".$value."</li>".",";
    }
    rtrim($data, ",");
    echo "</ul>";
}
foreach ($data as $key ) {
    echo $key;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>Volvo,</li><li>BMW</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Toyota,</li><li>Honda</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Mercedes</li>
</ul>
```

Notice that there is no comma after `BMW`, `Honda`, or `Mercedes`.

Comment: This seems kind of messy. What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? There might be a cleaner and simpler way.

Comment: i chunck the array and for the  each record I want to add a comma an remove the last one so an array should look like this array("Adrain, "Jonh,", "Ferguson") ;

Comment: I understand what your code does (and it doesn't work, you're trying to use `rtrim()` on an array), but I'm not sure what you're trying to do. For instance, you start with your input array of `array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Honda","Mercedes")`, what do you want it to look like when you're done?

Comment: array( array("Volvo,","BMW"),array("Toyota,","Honda"),array("Mercedes"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a less-loopy method that uses `array_splice()` instead of `array_chunk()`. No `count()` calls, no incrementing counters, just one loop.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2eaff9ec2b268d5b8724ad2de884a46f31d2f4d6))

```
$cars=array( "Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Honda","Mercedes");
while($cars){                             // while there are still elements in the array...
    $chunk=array_splice($cars,0,2);       // extract first two elements (reducing $cars)
    if(isset($chunk[1])){$chunk[0].=',';} // add comma to 1st element if 2nd element exists
    $output[]=$chunk;                     // add extracted elements to multi-dim output
}
var_export($output);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Volvo,',
    1 => 'BMW',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Toyota,',
    1 => 'Honda',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Mercedes',
  ),
)
```

---

The implementation for your unordered list is even simpler -- just add the comma to the joining string `</li><li>` in the `implode()` call: `,</li><li>`.  This also improved code versatility with larger "chunks".  (Whereas my first code is only suited for subarrays with two elements.)

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a9a2d3fe01bfe5008671c28230828b4800c8ee3))

```
$cars=array( "Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Honda","Mercedes");
while($cars){
    $chunk=array_splice($cars,0,2);
    echo "<ul><li>",implode(",</li><li>",$chunk),"</li></ul>";  // add comma to implode's glue string
}
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>Volvo,</li><li>BMW</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Toyota,</li><li>Honda</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Mercedes</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I see thanks for all, is hard to make a question understandable here hope i do better next time!

Comment: While it is pretty neat to use `array_splice` here, it can provide some unwanted side-effects as it is mutating the array itself. It quite far fetches, but say we want to display a total number of cars somewhere after this `ul`.

Comment: Yes, `array_splice()` modifies the original array, but if this is a problem for any reason, the fix is simple.  Total cars can be calculated before running the loop (no drama there).  To preserve a clone of the array, first line can be: `$cars=$tmp=array( "Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Honda","Mercedes");` and then just feed `$tmp` to `while`.  That's ...IF this is a concern at all.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample code you've provided, and the result you said you're looking for should be generated by the following:

```
$cars   = array( "Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Honda","Mercedes" );
$chunks = array_chunk( $cars, 2 );

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $chunks ); ++$i ) {
    for ( $j = 0; $j + 1 < count( $chunks[ $i ] ); ++$j ) {
        $chunks[ $i ][ $j ] .= ',';
    }
}
```

Now `$chunks` contains the multi-dimensional array you said you wanted in your comments along with the comments for each non-last element.

Comment: look closer i did that i say i need comma and remove last one

Comment: What you said was that you wanted to turn `array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Honda","Mercedes")` into `array( array("Volvo,","BMW"),array("Toyota,","Honda"),array("Merced‌​es"));` That's what the above code does. What comma are you wanting to remove?

Comment: dont you see it ?$chunks =(array_chunk($cars,2));  i told you 3 times lol what i try

Comment: array( array("Volvo, HERE IS COMMA","BMW HERE NOT"),array("Toyota,","Honda"),array("Merced‌​es"));

Comment: You should wrap code in comments in backticks so that it's easier to read :-). I've edited by answer so that it should now do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, my english is  not native is hard to talk and use programing quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do this in your view file, you can do something like this:

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Honda","Mercedes");

foreach (array_chunk($cars,2) as $chunk) {
    echo '<ul>', PHP_EOL;

    $keys = array_keys($chunk);
    $lastKey = array_pop($keys);
    foreach ($chunk as $key => $car) {
        echo '    ', '<li>', $car, $key !== $lastKey ? ',' : '', '</li>', PHP_EOL; 
    }

    echo '<ul>', PHP_EOL;
}
```

So basically we find the last key of each chunk before processing it, so we can determine whether to append comma or not. Pay attention, that stuff like `PHP_EOL` and `'    '` was added only for formatting and should be removed.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/80ba25be5353b86b7859472511ec38aa1766c538).

While this approach is fine inside the view, for other things it is better to format your data first and then display it (i.e. you should not echoing while traversing the data). The somewhat functional example will be:

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota","Honda","Mercedes");

$result = implode('', array_map(function ($items) { 
    $list = implode(',</li><li>', $items);

    return "<ul><li>$list</li></ul>";
}, array_chunk($cars,2)));

echo $result;
```